# Visual force section Size

Tags: visualforce

I have created a visual force page that is showed on the page layout of a custom object.
[image]

I have setted 100% like the next picture but the section is too small.
How can i set the size to for this visual force section?
is there some visual force tag?
[image]

BR

Comment: Are you creating a new section and adding the page or adding to an existing section in the page layout!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the 'Layout' to 1-Column, currently it is 2-Column.

This can be changed in the section properties.

[image]